# Test fitness proportionate selection algorithm implementation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, random-generation, weighted-sampling, genetic-algorithms

I implemented a couple of algorithms for [fitness proportionate selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) (roulette-wheel, alias method and roulette-wheel via stochastic acceptance) and now I want to write a test to ensure that generated samples have requested distribution.

So, from mathematical point of view I have following problem. Given two discrete distributions $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with $f(x_i) = p_i$ over $X=\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N\}$, where $p_i$ is known, and $\mathcal{W}(X)$, properties of which are unknown, I should test if $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{W}$ are the same without sampling from $\mathcal{P}$ (but I can sample from $\mathcal{W}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the job for a textbook [Pearson $\chi^2$ test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test). As this is well-described elsewhere, I will run the risk of giving a single-line answer with a reference to Wikipedia.